# How do I find out how many games I have won/lost with each race?

Tags: starcraft-2

How to find out how many games I have won with a specific race on ladder 1v1?

The profile screen just gives me the total wins and losses but I play with all three races and I would like to know my stats per race.

Thanks.

PS: I have been playing Starcraft from the release date but I don't have the old replays as I format my computer often.

Comment: I think that this question is duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15537/starcraft-2-how-do-i-know-how-many-games-i-played-per-race

Comment: @Meta: that question is one step short of what Chris is asking, but close :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to get statistics on your games is a program called [sc2gears](http://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/). It analyzes your replays and gives lots of data. To get this info, do a multi-replay-analysis on all of your replays, double-click your player name to do analysis on just you, and look at "Match-up Records".

That screen is a bit confusing though. It shows all the possible ways to express your match-ups. Your race is the first one (e.g. `PvZ` means you played Protoss, `ZvP` means you played Zerg). `*` means any, so `*vP` means your total stats against Protoss and `Pv*` means your total stats playing as Protoss. There is no consideration for "random".

Sounds like then you would be interested in the `Pv*`, `Zv*`, and `Tv*` rows.

*[update]*

sc2gears now supports a google-hosted [database](http://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/sc2gears-database) of all of your replays. This is basically the direct response to battle.net not showing win/loss data anymore.

Comment: this could work but I am formatting my computer quite often and I don't have the replays. I was wandering if battle.net has this kind of statistics

Comment: battle.net does not keep this information unfortunately; replays are your only hope.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclosure: I'm the author of Scelight and Sc2gears.*

---

[Scelight](https://sites.google.com/site/scelight/) (the successor to [Sc2gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/)) has been released which also has a Multi-replay analyzer which gives much more details, the number of won/lost games with each races is the least that is included.

Here's the [screenshot of the summarized race statistics](https://plus.google.com/photos/+AndrasBelicza/albums/5953539327596856001/5992825235347491810?pid=5992825235347491810&oid=117032417609730418656).

Of course you get all kinds of race matchup statistics broken down to game format.

Steps to acquire the desired won/lost numbers with each race:

1. Start Scelight.
2. On the `Replay Folders` page add a new replay folder if you have your replays in a custom folder (and not in the default folder which is already added).
3. Select this new Replay folder (the one whose replays you want to analyze), and click on the `Multi-Replay Analyze Selected Replay Folders` icon.
4. When the analysis is done, you will see a `Player` tab with all the players found in the replays.
5. Double click on your name (most likely it is the first if you analyzed your own replays). This will open the details of the player.
6. And now select the `Race` tab. This will show you summarized statistics for the races.
7. You can check out other tabs named after game format (like `1v1`, `2v2` etc.) which will show you more detailed race-matchup statistics of that game format only.

Comment: Both of these posts are almost word for word identical, and read an awful lot like spam.  Mind actually tailoring your answers to answer the question properly instead of using copy and paste?

Comment: Well, I posted almost the same answer because the questions are almost the same and not marked as duplicates.

Comment: So how about you explain how to use your program to get the information the asker wants, then?  Or, if they're the same, flag as duplicate?  And ensure you add in the disclosure that you're the author.  That's the minimum requirement for self-promotion here.

Comment: Ok, I'll go about explaining how to use it, and flag one as the duplicate of the other. Which one should be flagged as the duplicate of the other?

Comment: Either one, if you truly think they're duplicates.  I don't think they are; they're asking for different information.

Comment: Well, games won/lost per race includes the games played per race (played=won+lost), so this info is "superior" to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, flagged other question as duplicate, and edited this answer. Also deleted my other answer. You can clear these comments if you'd like to (delete them).

Comment: Also, since this is likely your software, judging by your profile, you need to disclose your affiliation with it, otherwise this can risk being considered spam.

Comment: Disclose in the answer itself?